# Source file name for output

Tags: windows, pdf, command-line-tool

I am trying to create a batch file using PDFtk to burst combine file in a certain directory to the output folder using the source file name (which can vary) as the input file name. for example

source directory :- D:\Temp\IN
destination directory :- D:\Temp\OUT
File name :- abcdefgh.pdf (which can vary)
desired output file name :- abcdefgh-001.pdf, abcdefgh-002.pdf and so on

My batch file will reside in D:\Script
The PDFtk.exe is in D:\PDFtk Server\bin

I tried for 1 whole day I can't get the input filename for the output.
Can anyone help

My existing program :-

```
CD D:\Temp\IN

for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b D:\Temp\IN\*.pdf') do (

set prefix=%%~ni )

set outname=%prefix%-%%03d-00.pdf 

path D:\PDFtk Server\bin

pdftk.exe D:\Temp\IN\%prefix% burst output D:\Temp\OUT\%outname%

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors in your approach the first one is that in a case like this you need local delayed expansion. For an initial `%` later use it as `!`.

```
CD D:\Temp\IN
```

This is ok but would be better if it allowed for /Drive shifting to "quoted drive folder" (beware input folder must NOT in this case be same as output folder with this approach, it is best if output is a sibling as you have done or use a common parent is better.)

`CD /D "D:\Temp\IN"`

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('dir /b D:\Temp\IN\*.pdf') do (

set prefix=%%~ni )
```

You have mixed up %%A and %%i they should be the same, `tokens` is not needed in this case but usebackq is for odd filenames and add quotes, don't need current directory, and `)` is way too early.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion  
for /f "usebackq delims=="  %%A in (`dir /b *.pdf`) do (
set "prefix=%%~nA"
```

next part

```
set outname=%prefix%-%%03d-00.pdf
```

again best quoted and needs using expansion
`set "outname=!prefix!-%%03d-00.pdf"`

```
path D:\PDFtk Server\bin

pdftk.exe D:\Temp\IN\%prefix% burst output D:\Temp\OUT\%outname%
```

better if combined and quoted you don't need to use Current Directory

`"D:\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe" "!prefix!.pdf" burst output "D:\Temp\OUT\!outname!"`

the terminal bracket goes here
`)`

```
exit
```

is superfluous

**so all in all**

```
CD /D "D:\Temp\IN"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "usebackq delims==" %%A in (`dir /b *.pdf`) do (
set "prefix=%%~nA"
set "outname=!prefix!-%%03d-00.pdf" 
"D:\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe" "!prefix!.pdf" burst output "D:\Temp\OUT\!outname!"
)
```

The whole command could be simplified to ONE line however to show where cuts can be made
**try this**

```
CD /D "D:\Temp"
for /f "usebackq delims==" %%A in (`dir /b IN\*.pdf`) do (
"D:\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe" "IN\%%~A" burst output "OUT\%%~nA-%%03d-00.pdf"
)
```

the need for `usebackq delims==` is because of later problems with characters such as `filename (1).pdf`

so we cannot shorten much more than

```
CD /D "D:\Temp" & for /f "usebackq delims==" %%A in (`dir /b IN\*.pdf`) do ("D:\PDFtk Server\bin\pdftk.exe" "IN\%%~A" burst output "OUT\%%~nA-%%03d-00.pdf")
```